# Set same frequency across all cores for benchmarking

Tags: linux, performance, x86, benchmarking

I wish to set the frequencies of all cores of my [Xeon e5-2660 v4 (Broadwell)](https://ark.intel.com/products/91772/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2660-v4-35M-Cache-2_00-GHz)  to the same value to remove variance in timing due to frequency fluctuations

Based on the available advice on this topic, I have tried the following (independently and in combination):

1. Set scaling governer to performance

`echo -n performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

2. Set the maximum and minimum frequencies in a tight range

```
echo 1990000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
echo 2010000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

3. Disabled the turbo boost option

`echo 1 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

4. Write the MSR associated with turbo boost

`wrmsr --all 0x1a0 0x4000850089`

Despite trying the above options, I am getting significant variance in CPU frequencies across different cores. Additionally, the frequency values of each core fluctuates significantly over time (measured using the following command - 
`cpufreq-info | grep "CPU freq"`

Why doesn't this work, and what should I do instead?

---

System information:  [Xeon e5-2660 v4 (Broadwell)](https://ark.intel.com/products/91772/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2660-v4-35M-Cache-2_00-GHz), 
Debian Stretch (kernel version 4.9)

**UPDATE 1:** I reverted back to kernel version 3.16 (used in Debian jessie) and I was able to get all cores at nominal frequency using just steps 1 and 3

**UPDATE 2**: I tested steps 1 and 3 on my laptop (Intel core i5-5300, arch linux, kernel 4.14.15-1) and the 4 logical processors did **NOT** settle at the nominal frequency. Adds support that the newer kernels make it difficult to control frequency

Comment: I usually measure in core clock cycles (with `perf stat`), not seconds, so I don't need to control for frequency.  In code with memory bottlenecks, it certainly matters (at half speed, DRAM latency is half as many clock cycles), but running close to peak mostly smooths that out.  Another thing I've sometimes done is run a busy-loop (with `_mm_pause()`) on one core to stop it from downclocking when mostly bottlenecked on memory and TLB misses.  Run it under `timeout` so you don't forget to kill it when you're done benchmarking.  Not an option if you need all your cores, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was unaware of this usecase of perf stat. However, I am benchmarking graph applications which have poor cache locality and, hence, spend a significant portion of the execution time doing DRAM accesses. Regarding busy-loops, I didn't understand your point about why that isn't an option if I need all my cores. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you're trying to benchmark a multithreaded workload, you don't have any spare cores to run a busy-loop on.  Skylake will sometimes downclock if it's spending most of its time cache missing.  (You can see this with `perf stat`).  But if there's a process that isn't cache missing, it will keep its core (and thus all the other cores) at max.  (The cores at least in a quad-core i7-6700k all seem to be in the same clock domain.)  So with `timeout -s INT 1h taskset -c 3 ./pauseloop` on one core, `taskset -c 2 ocperf.py -e cycles,uops_issue.any,... ./testlooop` on another, you can keep it pegged.

Comment: Interesting. The fact that these cores are in the same clock domain makes the case for a busy-loop. I am running on xeon processors with a large number of cores (e5-2660 v4). Will check if I can find information about how many core are in the same clock domain. Thanks for the info, you have given interesting nuggets!

Comment: Ah, yeah many-core Xeons probably have different clock domains.  It's probably a lot more common there to have one core running at max turbo while others are waking up for short amounts of work where power-saving is appropriate.  I wonder if this is part of the higher L3 latency on a Xeon, as well as just having more hops on the ring bus.

Comment: Setting the power governor to `performance` should turn off the "energy efficient turbo" thing where it scales down when there are lots of memory stalls, however. For me, `performance` + disabling turboboost (I use the msr for that ) works fine to lock my frequency at nominal. Are you seeing frequencies above or below nominal, or both? What about trying your same steps on a laptop or something to see if it works there?

Comment: Maybe you can try to disable EIST (Speedstep) in the BIOS settings (and also disable turboboost in the BIOS). (Don't forget to enable EIST after benchmarking.)

Comment: @BeeOnRope Across multiple observations, the core frequencies always seem to be lower than nominal. The funny thing is I was able to lock the CPUs at nominal frequency using steps 1 and 3 just a couple of days back (on debian jessie). However, I am unable to do the same once I updated to stretch a few days back.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may be hitting other limits, such as thermal, current draw or AVX frequency limits, all of which can force frequency below nominal regardless of other settings. There are sticky MSR bits you can use to track this. On Windows Intel XTU displays it graphically, on Linux I'm not sure.  @YetAnother

Comment: @wim I don't seem to have BIOS options for Speepstep or Turboboost. I think I was sucessful in disabling speedstep (maybe by step 3), because the tool `likwid-features -l ' reports speedstep as switched off. Additionally, the MSR for turbo-boost also seems to indicate that it should be off

Comment: @BeeOnRope oh. I am still a bit confused about how I was able to achieve this on jessie a few days back. My initial suspicion was whether this was an artifact of the kernel update in stretch

Comment: @YetAnother - well something could have changed any of the above factors. Maybe it got hotter, maybe your cooling solution has an issue, maybe a compiler or library update introduced a use of AVX where there was none before, etc.

Comment: If this was Skylake, an older kernel would be a more obvious explanation: With hardware P-states (`hwp`) which maybe on a new kernel enables, the scaling governor settings might not be used.  (And there might be different settings for the HWP min/max frequencies.)  But your E... v4 means Broadwell.

Comment: Hang on, did you *literally* run `echo 1990000 > /.../cpu*/...`?  Only the first filename of the glob expansion is used by the `>` operator, and all the rest are still args to `echo`.  I think you want `for f in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq; do echo 1990000 > "$f"; done`.  If older kernels didn't implement per-CPU settings but newer ones did, that would explain your observations.  Use `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_*` to dump the current settings as filename: contents

Comment: I ran the `echo 199000 > /../` in a script. I just included the kernel of the script for the sake of brevity. Maybe I should edit my question to help anybody with the same problem atleast cover the common bases?

Comment: You mention that 1 and 3 are sufficient on older kernels. You should be able to figure out which of 1 and 3 aren't working in the newer kernel based on observation: does turbo stop when you write to no_turbo?

Comment: I don't know how to check that. Writing to no_turbo does not turn off turbo boost (based on reading the corresponding MSR `rdmsr --all 0x1a0 -f 38:38`. Regarding the performance governor, the `cpufreq-info` command output seems to show that the "performance" governor can select any frequency between 1.2 and 3.2 GHz

Comment: Well you can use `turbostat` to monitor the actual CPU frequencies and observe if they go above nominal (the `-debug` flag also prints out a lot of good relevant info).

Comment: FWIW, I'm on kernel 4.10.0 and using intel_pstate and writing to `no_turbo` seems to work OK. It seems like changing the governor resets the turbo state though (to "on"), so that's something to watch out for. I use `cpupower` to change the governor, rather than writing to `/sys` but it's probably equivalent.